# LibGDX: Activity has leaked window when trying to post to Facebook

Tags: java, android, facebook, memory-leaks, libgdx

Context: I created a LibGDX game (extends AndroidApplication) that switches to another activity (extends FragmentActivity) to start a social Facebook sharing activity (extends Fragments). I followed the Tutorial here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/scrumptious/publish-open-graph-story#step6c

However, when I try to run my program, I get a Activity leaked window error. Full error log below:

```
01-07 00:20:33.160: E/WindowManager(23786): Activity com.pressx.thedevice.SocialActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@41cca0c0 that was originally added here
01-07 00:20:33.160: E/WindowManager(23786): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.pressx.thedevice.SocialActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@41cca0c0 that was originally added here
01-07 00:20:33.160: E/WindowManager(23786):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:374)
01-07 00:20:33.160: E/WindowManager(23786):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:307)
01-07 00:20:33.160: E/WindowManager(23786):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:239)
01-07 00:20:33.160: E/WindowManager(23786):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl$CompatModeWrapper.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:152)
01-07 00:20:33.160: E/WindowManager(23786):     at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:547)
01-07 00:20:33.160: E/WindowManager(23786):     at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:282)
01-07 00:20:33.160: E/WindowManager(23786):     at android.app.ProgressDialog.show(ProgressDialog.java:116)
01-07 00:20:33.160: E/WindowManager(23786):     at android.app.ProgressDialog.show(ProgressDialog.java:99)
01-07 00:20:33.160: E/WindowManager(23786):     at com.pressx.facebook.SelectionFragment.handleAnnounce(SelectionFragment.java:492)
01-07 00:20:33.160: E/WindowManager(23786):     at com.pressx.facebook.SelectionFragment.access$2(SelectionFragment.java:480)
01-07 00:20:33.160: E/WindowManager(23786):     at com.pressx.facebook.SelectionFragment$2.onClick(SelectionFragment.java:385)
01-07 00:20:33.160: E/WindowManager(23786):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4101)
01-07 00:20:33.160: E/WindowManager(23786):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17087)
01-07 00:20:33.160: E/WindowManager(23786):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
01-07 00:20:33.160: E/WindowManager(23786):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-07 00:20:33.160: E/WindowManager(23786):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-07 00:20:33.160: E/WindowManager(23786):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4849)
01-07 00:20:33.160: E/WindowManager(23786):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-07 00:20:33.160: E/WindowManager(23786):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-07 00:20:33.160: E/WindowManager(23786):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:795)
01-07 00:20:33.160: E/WindowManager(23786):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:562)
01-07 00:20:33.160: E/WindowManager(23786):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Reading around got me that maybe a ProgressDialog issue occurred. However, I followed the Facebook tutorial and ran the sample app that it created, no such error occurred.

Following are all locations of ProgressDialog and their contexts:

### Private Variable

```
private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
```

in

```
public class SelectionFragment extends Fragment {
    ...
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    ...
}
```

### ProgressDialog.show()

```
progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(getActivity(), "", getActivity().getResources().getString(R.string.progress_dialog_text), true);
```

in

```
private void handleAnnounce() {
    pendingAnnounce = false;
    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
    if(session == null || !session.isOpened())
        return;

    List<String> permissions = session.getPermissions();
    if(!permissions.containsAll(PERMISSIONS)) {
        pendingAnnounce = true;
        requestPublishPermissions(session);
        return;
    }
    progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(getActivity(), "", getActivity().getResources().getString(R.string.progress_dialog_text), true);
    AsyncTask<Void, Void, Response> task = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Response>() {
        @Override
        protected Response doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            HitAction hitAction = GraphObject.Factory.create(HitAction.class);
            for(BaseListElement element : listElements) {
                element.populateOGAction(hitAction);
            }
            Request request = new Request(Session.getActiveSession(), POST_ACTION_PATH, null, HttpMethod.POST);
            request.setGraphObject(hitAction);
            return request.executeAndWait();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Response response) {
            onPostActionResponse(response);
        }
    };
    task.execute();
}
```

### if() condition

```
if(progressDialog != null) {
    progressDialog.dismiss();
    progressDialog = null;
}
```

in

```
private void onPostActionResponse(Response response) {
    if(progressDialog != null) {
        progressDialog.dismiss();
        progressDialog = null;
    }

    if(getActivity() == null)
        return;

    PostResponse postResponse = response.getGraphObjectAs(PostResponse.class);
    if(postResponse != null && postResponse.getId() != null) {
        String dialogBody = String.format(getString(R.string.result_dialog_text), postResponse.getId());
        new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity()).setPositiveButton(R.string.result_dialog_button_text, null).setTitle(R.string.result_dialog_title).setMessage(dialogBody).show();
        init(null);
    }
    else
        handleError(response.getError());
}
```

Full Code Here: https://github.com/putty174/TheDevice/blob/Max/TheDevice-android/src/com/pressx/facebook/SelectionFragment.java